# need help accessing Firestore sub-collection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a novice when it comes to coding (started teaching myself ~year ago), any help will be much appreciated, thank you in advance.

I saw that there is 3-4 other post on stack overflow on how to access Firestore's sub-collections.
I tried them all and had no luck, hence why I'm posting this as a new question.

right now I have my data set is up as: collection/document.array. And that was fine till now because I just needed to read that data from the array to draw it out in my little React project with .reduce and .map and push new data to that array on input.
[image]
[image]

this is the code I have right now for getting data from Firestore:

```
--- in firebase.js ----------------------------------------------------------------------
export const fire = firebase.initializeApp(config);
export const db = fire.firestore()
_________________________________________________________________________________________

--- in events-context.js ----------------------------------------------------------------

 const fetchEvents = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await db.collection('events').get();
      setEvents(data.docs.map(doc => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
    } catch ({ message }) {
      alert(`Error @ fetchEvents, Error:${message}`);
    } 
  };
```

But now I want to add edit and a remove feature, but in order to do that, I need to carry out my array of data into a sub-collection so each individual element from that array had its own id so that I could later target it. so it needs to be set up something like this: collection/document/sub-collection
[image]

Comment: What is the question? How to chain together `.collection` and `.document` calls?

Comment: sorry if my question wasn’t clear. I did try to chain db.collection(‘events’).doc(`${id}`).collection(‘payers’).get() also I tried db.collection(`events/${id}/payers`).get() but neither worked for me. I read the documentation on it and stack overflow answers but non worked. My question is how to do it so it works, or am I doing something wrong because it doesn’t work? I tried debugging to the best of my novice abilities, but came short and couldn’t find an explanation why it doesn’t work.

Comment: How are you getting the `id` that you're using in the chained call? That call looks reasonable to me (although it's unnecessary to interpolate the `id` -- it can just be `.doc(id)`)

Comment: im getting that id from another state i have 
in order for a dropdown, i have to work I need an array of options consisting of  name and value , so name = name and value = id

and yes i probably can and should use it without it being a template literal.

Answer (score 0):

To access a document inside a collection, you must know the document ID from another source. This can be done by managing the names inside an array of strings or maps that you can then process within your app per your design.

For example: once created, you will have a snapshot of the reference of which you can store the document id inside the parent document:

```
db.collection("events").doc(id).update({
    payers: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(paySnapshot.ref.id)
})`
```

Once you have this information, you can append it to the relevant document path using one of the following techniques.

- `db.collection("events").doc(id).collection("payers").doc(pay_id).get()`
- `db.doc(\`events/${id}/payers/${pay_id}`).get()`

I strongly advise against using `.get()` on a collection without `limit()` and `where()` conditions to reduce the reads that can occur.

Comment: i have a state that holds the event ids that i was trying to use, i think it didn't work because i was trying to pass an array to it, that's why it didn't work. 

and i do use array union to push to this array:

```
 const addPayer = async newPaymentInfo => {
    await db
      .collection('events')
      .doc(newPaymentInfo.id)
      .update({
        payers: firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(...newPaymentInfo.payers)
      });
  };
```
but i don't really understand where you're getting this from `paySnapshot.ref.id`

Comment: I assumed the name in reference to the snapshot when creating the new document. you can generate a document and fetch the ID locally before committing. you can swap it out with what you need.

Comment: db.collection("events").doc(id).collection("payers").doc(pay_id).get()

i understand this line but how can i get all of them and not just one

hence my question if something like this would work: db.collection("events").doc(id).collection("payers").get()

if i am understanding your code correctly this ``db.doc(\events/${id}/payers/${pay_id}`).get()`` would fetch an individual document ? 

but I'm not interested in doing a ton of individual calls to DB, I rather receive a giant array and then map or reduce it.

Comment: then you can simply use `.get()` on the collection, this returns an array of snapshots

Comment: gotcha thanks I will try it out right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me :)

**Insert data >>>**

```
const q = query(collection(this.fire, "events"));
         const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
         const queryData = querySnapshot.docs.map((details) => ({
           ...details.data(),
           id: details.id,
         }));
         console.log(queryData);
 
     queryData.map(async (v, id) => {
       await setDoc(doc(this.fire, `events/${auth}/more`, events.title), {
         'title': events.title,
         'uid': auth,
 //your data here
           })
         })
```

**Read Data >>>**

```
 const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(this.fire,
 `/events/${auth}/more/`)); querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {   //
 doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots  
 console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data()); }); 
return querySnapshot;
```